# Convert / Cast StructType, ArrayType to StringType (Single Valued) using pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, pyspark

**One of my Dataframe(spark.sql) has this schema.**

```
root
 |-- ValueA: string (nullable = true)
 |-- ValueB: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- abc: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |-- a0: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- a1: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- a2: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- a3: string (nullable = true)
 |-- ValueC: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- pqr: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |-- info1: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- info2: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- x1: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- x2: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- x3: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- info3: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- info4: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Value4: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- xyz: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |-- b0: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- b2: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- b3: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Value5: string (nullable = true)
```

**I need to save this to CSV file but without using any flatten, explode in the below format.**

```
 |-- ValueA: string (nullable = true)
 |-- ValueB: struct (nullable = true)
 |-- ValueC: struct (nullable = true)
 |-- ValueD: struct (nullable = true)
 |-- ValueE: string (nullable = true)
```

**I have Directly used the command `[df.to_pandas().to_csv("output.csv")]` this serves my purpose, but I need a better approach. I am using pyspark**

Answer (score 1):

In Spark writing `csv` format doesn't support writing `struct/array..etc` complex types yet.

**`Write as Parquet file:`**

Better approach in Spark would be writing as **`parquet`** format, As parquet format supports all the **`nested data types`** and provides better performance while reading/writing.

```
df.write.parquet("<path>")
```

---

**`Write as Json file:`**

In case writing in json format accepted then

```
df.write.json("path")
#or
df.toJSON().saveAsTextFile("path")
```

---

**`Write as CSV file:`**

Use **`to_json`** function which converts json **`struct/Array`** to **`string`** and store as csv format.

```
df.selectExpr("valueA","to_json(ValueB)"..etc).write.csv("path")
```

Comment: Thank you for your response @Shu.
Well, I only want the format in (CSV). I have tried doing 'to_json(ValueB)'. This saves the file as CSV but the created file has unwantedly broken up columns. I guess those are from the to_json format.